# Launch IE from app passing HTML content

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to launch IE from my WP7 app and load the HTML to create the page dynamically. The HTML is read from a web service and can change at any time, so I'm not able to just store the HTML in a file. Is there a way to do this -- much like you do with WebBrowser.NavigateToString(strHtml)?
-Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use WebBrowser.NavigateToString() with the webservice's address?

Comment: Application requirement that the page needs to be launched in the browser. I was using WebBrowser, but was handed new req.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to open your HTML content in an embedded [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) control you can use the "NavigateToString" function and pass it the HTML content you would like to load.

If you are trying to open it in the native IE browser on the device then I would recommend putting state information in the URL and opening the page directly with any parameters required to replicate the view in the browser via the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). This way you wouldn't technically be opening the HTML code from your app but you would be able to ensure that the HTML content loaded from your service is correct based on your query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Shawn L and willmel, but unfortunately, I can't use a uri that points to a page on the server side; the HTML needs to be returned via an existing web service method and I need to display the content within the IE browser.